# Bootstrap modal body content outside modal

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I had this bootstrap modal on  a twig template:

```
{# empty Twig template #}
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="clientsModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Seleccionar fechas</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label for="from">Desde</label>
                    <input class="form-control datepicker" type="text" id="from">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label for="until">Hasta</label>
                    <input class="form-control datepicker" type="text" id="until">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="clients-report-search">Buscar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Labels and inputs are inside `modal-body` div but are shown outside the
[div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSpIa.png)

Labels are  shown inside the modal footer instead body

Comment: what version of bootstrap?

Comment: I'm using bootstrap 3.3.7

Comment: can you add working snippet

Comment: can you share screenshot of modal?

Comment: there is a link to the modal scrrenshot

Comment: Well the accepted answer is workaround to make your code work. I suggest you to make use of the structure bootstrap prescribes. You are using "col" without row - first mistake. Additionally you have inputs, which should be incorporated under form tag. So I suggest don't be in hush to accept the solution, consider semantics too!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:-

You can use just `<div class="clearfix"></div>` before `<div class="modal-footer">`

or

You can use `overflow:hidden;` with `modal-content` class like below:-

```
 <div class="modal-content" style="overflow:hidden;">
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add `row` after `modal-body`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#clientsModal">Open Modal</button>

<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="clientsModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Seleccionar fechas</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label for="from">Desde</label>
                    <input class="form-control datepicker" type="text" id="from">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label for="until">Hasta</label>
                    <input class="form-control datepicker" type="text" id="until">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="clients-report-search">Buscar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code snippet a bit. Please try now if its solves the problem

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#clientsModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="clientsModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Seleccionar fechas</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="from">Desde</label>
            <input class="form-control datepicker" type="text" id="from">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="until">Hasta</label>
            <input class="form-control datepicker" type="text" id="until">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="clients-report-search">Buscar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm using bootstrap 3.3.7